# Group by Latest value

Tags: mysql, sql

I only want to show the latest value.

Here is the table:

| InstanceID | InstanceDate | TotalProjects |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-14 | 69 |
| 1 | 2021-10-12 | 70 |
| 2 | 2021-10-14 | 20 |
| 3 | 2021-10-14 | 89 |
| 3 ​ | 2021-10-13 | 99 |
| 3 | 2021-10-11 | 100 |
| 4 ​ | 2021-10-12 | 12 |
| 4 | 2021-10-14 | 13 |
| 5 ​ | 2021-10-14 | 0 |

Here is the query I used to get this table:

```
SELECT "InstanceID", MAX("Date"), "TotalProjects"
FROM "BI_InstanceMetric"
GROUP BY "InstanceID", "TotalProjects"
ORDER BY "InstanceID"
```

This is what I want:

| InstanceID | InstanceDate | TotalProjects |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-14 | 69 |
| 2 | 2021-10-14 | 20 |
| 3 | 2021-10-14 | 89 |
| 4 | 2021-10-14 | 13 |
| 5 | 2021-10-14 | 0 |

I'd appreciate if someone help me, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please fix any syntax errors if present:

```
SELECT "InstanceID", "InstanceDate", "TotalProjects"
FROM "BI_InstanceMetric" as ORIGINAL_TABLE
JOIN (SELECT "InstanceID", MAX("InstanceDate") as "InstanceDate"
FROM "BI_InstanceMetric"
GROUP BY "InstanceID") as MAX_TABLE
ON MAX_TABLE."InstanceID" = ORIGINAL_TABLE."InstanceID"
AND MAX_TABLE."InstanceDate" = ORIGINAL_TABLE."InstanceDate"
```

Comment: thanks i just deleted the original_table alias and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to mark the rows you want. Then filtering is tricial.

For example:

```
select
  InstanceID, Date, TotalProjects
from (
  select *,
    row_number(over partition by InstanceID
               order by InstanceDate desc) as rn
  from BI_InstanceMetric
) x
where rn = 1
```